# Problemas em navegação React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, react, react-router-dom

Tenho uma aplicação feita em React e estou utilizando navegação através do React Router DOM.

Quando eu navego no código utilizando /login por exemplo, para redirecionar para a página de login, ele funciona perfeitamente e me leva até a página: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIHIK.png

Porém, quando eu navego direto pela url colocando na mão o /login ou qualquer outra navegação que não seja o "/", ele me retorna página não encontrada: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cy8o.png

No localhost funciona, ao subir para o apache, da este erro.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './paginas/login/Login';
import Dashboard from './paginas/dashboard/Dashboard';
import { PrivateRoute } from './privateRoute';

function Rotas() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/login" element={ <Login />} />
                <Route path="/" element={ 
                    <PrivateRoute>
                        <Dashboard />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                } />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Rotas;
```

Answer (score -1):

No apache tens de criar esta configuração:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

E depois tens de criar um ficheiro .htaccess na pasta do teu projeto:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```